# Adding to File Menu in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, user-interface

How can I add items to the file menu in IE ? Is it at all possible ? I know we can add to context menu, help menu, toolbars and in Explorer bars. But can we add to the file menu or edit menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  IE doesn't support extensibility at this point.

Back in the day you might have hacked it, but Low Rights IE and Loosely Coupled IE make it impossible.